# Lightning Effect CSS

Tags: html, css

EDIT:
I'm basically trying to achieve the result that this web page demonstrates.
http://codepen.io/Chrislion_me/pen/rVqwbO

I'm pretty new to the whole HTML / CSS world.
What I'm trying to do for a project at uni, is create a home page where there's a picture of a lightning storm in the background, covered by a overlay which is too filter out some of the picture [Picture of current website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlDue.jpg).

Basically, the photo has to remain fixed where it is, so if I scrolled further down the page it doesn't move as such [Stationary Lightning Storm][2].

So this is working perfectly fine, problem is, I can't get my lightning storm to work correctly, the storm is meant to flash a couple of times every ~ 8 seconds-ish.

Depending on the way I play with the code, it usually just goes white and then every ~ 8 seconds it flashes the image and then goes white again.
I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, I've posted part of my code below if that helps - it's just section that hosts the image and the buttons, I can post more CSS if that's needed.

Thanks in advance! :)

HTML

```
<div id="bg" class="banner flashit">
<p>TEST TEXT</p>
<ul class="actions">
<li><a href="#" class="button special big">Click here</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#bg{
   padding: 16em 0 13em 0;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), url("../images/banner.jpg");
   background-position: center top;
   background-size: cover;
   line-height: 1.75;
   text-align: center;
   z-index: -2;
}
.banner {
    padding: 16em 0 13em 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), url("../images/banner.jpg");
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: cover;
    line-height: 1.75;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(3);
    filter: brightness(3);
    -o-filter: brightness(3);
    -moz-filter: brightness(3);
    z-index: -1;
}   
.flashit{
    -webkit-animation: flash ease-out 10s infinite;
    -moz-animation: flash ease-out 10s infinite;
    animation: flash ease-out 10s infinite;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    from { opacity: 0; } 
    92% { opacity: 0; }
    93% { opacity: 0.6; }
    94% { opacity: 0.2; }
    96% { opacity: 0.9; } 
    to { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes flash {
    from { opacity: 0; } 
    92% { opacity: 0; }
    93% { opacity: 0.6; }
    94% { opacity: 0.2; }
    96% { opacity: 1; } 
    to { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with your CSS for the animation. Specifically the keyframes.

In keyframes, if you use `from{}` and `to{}` these are the same as "start" and "end". You can't *also* use percentages in between. From and to are all you can use when going that route. There can be no "middle" steps when using `from{}` and `to{}`.

If you want to use percentages for keyframes, all steps need to be a percentage. So rather than using `from()`, use `0%` and instead of `to{}`, use `100%`.

On top of this, since you had all the percentages set to the 90% range and the animation is 10 seconds long, starting from 0% opacity, there was a period of about 11 seconds (2 second delay, then 9 seconds of the animation) where the image is just transparent and it appears as though nothing's there. Changing the percentages to *start* the flashing at the beginning of the animation then ending on an opaque image helps this considerably.

Ultimately alterations merely came down to tweaking the keyframes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    0% { opacity: 1; } 
    2% { opacity: 0; }
    3% { opacity: 0.6; }
    4% { opacity: 0.2; }
    6% { opacity: 0.9; } 
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes flash {
    0% { opacity: 1; } 
    2% { opacity: 0; }
    3% { opacity: 0.6; }
    4% { opacity: 0.2; }
    6% { opacity: .9; } 
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

In the future it's often easier to get helpful answers if you can set up a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of your issue.

I've created a **[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/n2z3gy9g/)** with the modified keyframes, and different images since I don't have access to your images.

Comment: So I tried that and it doesn't quite work with my template, I obtained the code for the lightning from here; 
http://codepen.io/Chrislion_me/pen/rVqwbO

It doesn't look quite right because it now permanently looks like this;
http://imgur.com/yxxvPVv

Comment: So I removed the code from the CSS that brings out the brightness in the image, but it unfortunately doesn't create the same effect that I'm chasing in the link;
http://codepen.io/Chrislion_me/pen/rVqwbO

Any idea how I can amend the code to allow it too look like that?

Comment: @DeonWilliams a great deal of that sample is dependent upon the image being used. The filter isn't going to work for every image or may need adjusting. In all probability, you won't get the *exact* same appearance unless you use the *exact* same image. Really you just have to tweak it and play with it to get to where you want. I can do that, but there's no way for me to know if what I think is aesthetically pleasing matches what you want. You need to do it yourself.

Comment: Yes I agree with that in regards to the aesthetics, but correct me if I am wrong. But in the sample I provided;(http://codepen.io/Chrislion_me/pen/rVqwbO)  does that use the image in its stock / raw form as the background image, and then the CSS instructs the same image (now used twice) with increased brightness which gives the affect of lightning - to be flashed over the top of background image? 

Sorry for the questions, I just can't grasp what the codes doing exactly and why it's not providing the desired effect I need.
Thank you.

Comment: Correct, but in your code you're using multiple background images in **one** container..... The sample has **two** containers - one flashes, the other does not

Comment: Or am I reading it wrong, does the plain unedited image sit on top of the image which has increased brightness, then the CSS instructs the opacity of the top layer to decrease for a very short period of time?

Comment: So how would you advise to me to amend my HTML in order for it to use the two containers without compromising the layout? 

Thanks again, you've been a big help so far!